# Expected value of w for f(y)=1/14 e^-14y , y>0 and w = [y]

Tags: probability, expected-value

I'm trying to calculate expected value of this density function $$f(y)=(\frac{1}{14})e^{\frac{-1}{14}y} , y>0 , w = [y]$$

but I'm struggling with computing the floor function while it's going to infinity.

anyone help solving this problem?

Comment: Please use MathJax to format your equations. Also, there is something wrong in your definitions. You have $f(y)$ on the left hand side, but an expression of $x$ on the right hand side.

Comment: thanks for your note @Andrei

Comment: Hint: The probability that $w=0$ is $P(w=0)= \int_{y=0}^1 \exp(-y/14)/14\; dy$.  The probability that $w=1$ is $P(w=1)=P(w=0)\cdot \exp(-1/14)$.  More generally, $P(w=n)=P(w=n-1)\cdot \exp(-1/14)$ when $n>1$.

Answer (score 0):

$$E(w)=E([y])=\frac{1}{14}\int_{1}^{2}[Y]e^{\frac{-1}{14}y}dy + \frac{1}{14}\int_{2}^{3}[Y]e^{\frac{-1}{14}y}dy+...$$

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{14}\int_{k}^{k+1}ke^{\frac{-1}{14}y}dy = \lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n k(e^{\frac{-k}{14}}-e^{\frac{-(k+1)}{14}})$$

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} (e^{\frac{-1}{14}}+e^{\frac{-2}{14}}+e^{\frac{-3}{14}}+...+e^{\frac{-n}{14}}-ne^{\frac{-(n+1)}{14}})$$

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} ({\frac{e^{\frac{-1}{14}}-e^{\frac{-(n+1)}{14}}}{1-e^{\frac{-1}{14}}}} -ne^{\frac{-(n+1)}{14}})={\frac{1}{e^\frac{1}{14}-1}}$$